# Ephemeral Responses in Slack for BotFramework

Tags: botframework

I'm new to the Botframework, but am making some great headway. I've got a bot up and running and it works great for DM chats in Slack, but I'd like my bot's responses to be only to asking user in a chatroom/group instead being broadcast to the group.

Reading up on [Slack](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_to_a_command), it looks like if I set the response_type to "ephemeral", this should solve the problem. Sounds potentially easy enough, but no idea if we have the ability to override this in the dialog context / activity. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [NodeJS SDK Documentation for Sessions](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/session#cards) and scroll down to the **Cards** section, you will find a handy little function of the Message class

`Message.sourceEvent()`

From the same documentation page:

> It’s not practical for the SDK to support every card or attachment
>   format supported by the underlying chat service so we have a
>   Message.sourceEvent() method that you can use to send custom messages
>   & attachments in the channel native schema.

Which means that you can use `Message.sourceEvent()` to do exactly what you are trying do: alter the structure of your outgoing message object.

Here is a code snippet for your specific case that I tried out:

```
//test slack source event messaging
var msg = new botbuilder.Message(session).sourceEvent({
    slack: {
        response_type: "ephemeral",
        text: "This is a test Slack message.",
        attachments: [
            {
                text: "Test inlaid message."
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

When you pass the current `session` to the `Message()` class, it populates all the address info in the Message so you don't have to do any of that. [You can see for yourself here in the documentation for the Message's constructor method.](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.message.html#constructor)

Then, you just call `sourceEvent()` and pass in an object, with the name of the channel you are constructing a message for (in this case slack), and then fill out the desired message data. This allows you to define your `response_type: "ephemeral"`.

[Documentation for sourceEvent() here.](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.message.html#sourceevent)